# How do we integrate vue-admin with vue-js?

Tags: vuejs2, bulma

I have vuejs installed and would like to use vue admin (https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin) with it, however the documentation does not mention how to use it.

For example, if I wanted to use a component from vue-admin then what are the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to git clone the `vue-admin` project repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin.git my-vue-admin
```

Then:

```
cd my-vue-admin
```

Next, install all the dependencies:

```
npm install
```

Once all the dependencies are installed, run:

```
npm run dev
```

Wait for the compilation to finish then go to `http://localhost:8080` in your browser and it should be working.

**Using individual components only**

If you would like to use some components only, for example: *a modal component*. Then find its npm package name and install it in your project.

You can either look for the name in `package.json` or look at the source code of the page using that component in vue-admin. For example, a modal is used [here](https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin/blob/7098eab3c180c14ade4b73238c988ef4d2b29327/client/views/components/modals/Modal.vue).

Vue-admin is using **vue-bulma-modal** component. Here is its [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bulma-modal) which can provide you with more information.

Comment: Cloning would give me the entire repo, I just want to maybe clone it and then use individual components only, like a modal, or button ...

Answer (score 1):

vue-admin is more of a project template, so you'd make a copy of the whole project and make changes as needed. If you want to use individual components, just install them as needed and refer to vue-admin as example

Comment: But how do you install individual components? I know how to install the entire project, but what if I just need a modal?